# JS Change the cursor for an image stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, css, image, cursor, setattribute

Is it possible to change the cursor with a customized image stored in a variable?

I have tried setAttribute or .style.cursor, but it does not seems to work..

Here are some examples of what I have tried:

```
var MyImage = MyImage.png;
document.getElementById("DivWithMouseOverEvent").style.cursor = MyImage;
```

I also tried:

```
var MyImage = MyImage.png;
document.getElementById("DivWithMouseOverEvent").setAttribute("cursor", MyImage);
```

The idea is that the var MyImage may change depending on some actions by the user.

I know Firefox requires a second cursor option, but I do not know how to do it with a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code given.

The image definition needs to be not only a string, but also a url.

Also, a fallback is mandatory (not just required by Firefox).

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) for more detail on what is allowed.

```js
let MyImage = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ9aI.png';
document.getElementById("DivWithMouseOverEvent").style.cursor = 'url(' + MyImage + '), grab';
```

```css
#DivWithMouseOverEvent {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="DivWithMouseOverEvent"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of the url('') requirement for .cursor, but I did not know how I could add a variable inside of it (or if it actually had to be replaced).

But you actually spotted exactly what I needed so thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is my example. Hope it can help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="title">
      This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling involved!
    </h1>
    <script>
      const cursor = "Ball.cur";
      const url = `url(${cursor}), auto`;
      const title = document.getElementById("title");

      title.style.cursor = url;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the url() considers the ${cursor} as a string instead of a variable in my JS file. Am I missing something from your example?

Answer (score 0):

### -------**Simply run this code direct to confirm please**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .cursor{
            cursor: wait;
        }
        div.cursor{
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="cursor" >
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, nobis cupiditate mollitia expedita voluptatibus quas sunt? Voluptatibus neque harum pariatur, laboriosam facere autem dolor reiciendis, quas necessitatibus est, amet quia?
    </div>

    <script>
        
        
            $(function () {
                $('.cursor').on('mouseenter', function(){
                    $(this).css({'cursor': "url('https://ani.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-9/oth927.cur'), auto", 'color':'orange', 'padding': '8px'});
                })
            })
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am actually not used yet to JQuery, I am quite new to this. Is it more powerful or does it have unique useful tools/functions?